# Angular deployment problem with app in subdirectory

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, tomcat9

I'm getting "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec." error after deployment of an angular application.

Application was working fine before Nx instalation. I'm trying to get rid off Nx by the moment.

As far as I investigated, all says that the issue is that base-href is missing, but is not. I have it in the package.json and it is perfectly exported in the index.html file.

This is the section in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prebuild": "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prebuild-local": "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch",
    "build-local": "ng build --configuration=local --base-href=/app_name/angular/",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration=prod --base-href=/AppName/angular/",
    "build-test": "ng build --configuration=testing --base-href=/AppName/angular/",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

And this is what I got in the index.html

```
<base href="/app_name/angular/">
```

I create the distributions files with this command: `npm run build-local` and then copy files to a Apache Tomcat in `http://localhost:8080/app_name/angular/`

I have "rewrite" rules added in Tomcat as sugested in [CodeDumpster](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/)

Rewrite rule is like `RewriteRule ^/app_name/angular/(.*) /app_name/angular/index.html`

What else can I check?

Comment: Did you check the network tab, which HTML document is returned by the web server?

Comment: it is returning index.html

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

The issue was not the Angular or Nx instalation. It was a issue with the rewrite rule.

The example I followed was only (but it was not specified) for one rewrite rule. I added several more in this way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/application01/angular/(.*) /application01/angular/index.html
RewriteRule ^/application02/apps/(.*) /application02/apps/index.html
```

Missing to repeat the "RewriteCond" instruction and missing to add the "[L]". It has to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/application01/angular/(.*) /application01/angular/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/application02/apps/(.*) /application02/apps/index.html [L]
```

Thanks any way